# Join the numbers that is seperated by comma

Tags: javascript

I have an array and the array contains 1 to 31 but the problem is that when the number is greater than 9 starting from 10 to 31 it prints like this format for example 10, 1,0 eleven 1,1 thirty 3,0 so how do I join these numbers without effecting the other numbers below 10 so how do I make it print it correctly from 10 to 31.

```
       let arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", 
       "1", "4", "1", "5", "1", "6", "1", "7", "1", "8", "1", "9", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
       "3", "2", "4", "2", "5", "2", "6", "2", "7", "2", "8", "2", "9", "3", "0", "3", "1"]
```

Comment: how would you kwon that "1", "1" is eleven and not two times "1" ?

Comment: It is how many days that is in the month of May I hope that makes sense.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join use this

Comment: No "1","1" is eleven I guarantee you that.

Comment: but how could you know in advance this if you want a "code" solution? (you have for isntance , `` "1", "1", "1"` in the array, is it ``11, 1`? is `111`? Is it `1, 11`? actually, it's `11` and the beginning of `12`!)

Comment: The simplest way would be to simply recreate an array of the numbers 1 to 31, as string, or change the way this array you show is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any straightforward way of doing this other than good o'l loops.

```
let newArr = arr.slice(0, 9)

for (let a = 9; a < arr.length - 1; a+=2)
    newArr.push(arr[a] + arr[a+1])
```

Comment: Nice way to skip first 9 numbers :D

Comment: it works thank you, man, you are the true hero after the health care people.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over the wanted size of a number and a count and get a new size if you rach one and if the next item with the size as offet is a zero, then increment size

```js
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "4", "1", "5", "1", "6", "1", "7", "1", "8", "1", "9", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "4", "2", "5", "2", "6", "2", "7", "2", "8", "2", "9", "3", "0", "3", "1", "3", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "5", "3", "6", "3", "7", "3", "8", "3", "9", "4", "0", "4", "1", "4", "2", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "5", "4", "6", "4", "7", "4", "8", "4", "9", "5", "0", "5", "1", "5", "2", "5", "3", "5", "4", "5", "5", "5", "6", "5", "7", "5", "8", "5", "9", "6", "0", "6", "1", "6", "2", "6", "3", "6", "4", "6", "5", "6", "6", "6", "7", "6", "8", "6", "9", "7", "0", "7", "1", "7", "2", "7", "3", "7", "4", "7", "5", "7", "6", "7", "7", "7", "8", "7", "9", "8", "0", "8", "1", "8", "2", "8", "3", "8", "4", "8", "5", "8", "6", "8", "7", "8", "8", "8", "9", "0", "0", "9", "1", "9", "2", "9", "3", "9", "4", "9", "5", "9", "6", "9", "7", "9", "8", "9", "9", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1"],
    result = array.reduce(((size, count) => (r, v, i, a) => {
        if (v === '1') {
            let j = 0;
            while (a[i + ++j] === '0') ;
            if (j > size) count = size++;
        }
        if (++count < size) {
            r[r.length - 1] *= 10
            r[r.length - 1] += +v;
        } else {
            r.push(+v);
            count = 0;
        }
        return r;
    })(1, 0), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```